How can I search for tags with that include a specified string in their Usage Guidance?
I would like to search for all tags (on Stack Overflow) that include some specific string in the Usage Guidance portion of their Tag Wiki.  How can I do that?
Specifically I would like to search for all tags whose usage guidance includes the string "off-topic".  Using Google and prior experience, I found:

SEO.
Licensing.
agile.
appstore-approval.

But I have no reason to believe this list is exhaustive.  How can I find all of them e.g. by using the Data Explorer?  The closest query I could find is Tag with no usage guidance, but it has a tag wiki, can you help us summarize it?.
(This question is inspired by the recent change to the tag hover text which no longer shows the usage guidance.)

A feature request to allow tag wikis to be searched was deferred ten years ago.

Google with 'site:' & the site plus '/tags' & your phrase in double quotes. site://stackoverflow.com/tags "off-topic" (I just went to a tag wiki & took as much of the URL as I could that was not tag-specific & I know about 'site:'.) (A problem with searching meta.stackexchange.com tags is that all the meta sites are under the same URL.)

In SEDE, the Tags table has a column ExcerptPostId which references the Posts table. That limits the Posts table well enough that a full body search  is possible, and the resulting query is relatively simple.


Thanks!  121 rows returned.  That's a lot of somewhat off-topic tags.
